# Scanning through ArrayList for Objects with same field

Tags: java, object, for-loop, arraylist

I have a simple class Creator:

```
public class Creator {

    private String name;

    public Creator(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

I am scanning an XML document to make more Creator objects, which will be added to an ArrayList.

However, I do not want a new Creator to be added if there is already an existing Creator with the same 'name' field in my ArrayList. Here is my attempt below, but what would be the best way of doing this?

```
ArrayList<Creator> creators = new ArrayList<>();
String text; // name from XML input    

boolean makeCreator = true;
for(Creator creator : creators) {
    if(creator.getName().equals(text)) {
        makeCreator = false;
    }
}
if(makeCreator == true) {
    creators.add(new Creator(text));
}
```

Comment: Does this code you show work and you would like to know how to write it better?

Comment: Sorry, yes my code does work. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of carrying out this type of operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a set implementation (such as HashSet), which does not allow duplicates.

This would require to implement equals and hashcode method in your data class

```
public class Creator {

private String name;

public Creator(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int hashCode() {
    return name.hashCode();
}

public boolean equals(Object other) {
   if (!(other instanceof Creator)) {
      return false;
   }
   return Objects.equals(((Creater)other).name, name);
}
```

}
Be aware that you might want to have a better implementation of both methods.

The question is - what is `creators` collection you already have ? You iterate over it and then create a new list ?

So the answer might be

```
Set<Creator> uniqeCreators = new HashSet<>(creators);
```

oh yeah and `if(makeCreateor == true)` is redundant, `if (makeCreator)` is enough

Comment: `other.name` won't compile. It needs to be `((Creator) other).name`.

Answer (score 2):

You just want to see if there is a Creator object with the same name already, correct?

If so, just override equals, to be:

```
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof Creator) {
        return name.equalsIgnoreCase(((Creator) object).name);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then to test for existing just do `creators.contains(new Creator(name));`

Comment: If you're going to override `equals`, you really should override `hashcode`, too.

Answer (score 1):

The datastructure that you need is a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). The definition states that:

> A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one
>   value.

so simply key it on the name. Any time you need the `Creator`s themselves, access them via [values()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--), and if absolutely necessary to have an `ArrayList`, convert the resulting `Collection` to an `ArrayList` using [its constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-). If maintaining the insertion order is important, use a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

```
Map<Creator> creators = new LinkedHashMap<>();
String text; // name from XML input    
creators.putIfAbsent(text, new Creator(text));
ArrayList<Creator> creatorList = new ArrayList<>(creators.values());
```

This avoids needing to override `equals`/`hashCode`, which, aside from the extra code/maintenance, can cause issues if you start adding other properties to `Creator`. It also gives `O(1)` performance on inserts, an advantage over `O(n)` checking across the `ArrayList`, although indexed queries directly against `values()` will suffer (if that is important), as they will be `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can override `equals` and `hashCode` in `Creator` and use `creators.contains()`.

An alternative approach is to use a `Set<String>`.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
List<Creator> creators = new ArrayList<>();
...
String text = (get somehow)
if (set.add(text))
    creators.add(new Creator(text));
```

This relies on `Set.add` returning `true` if the `String` was added to the `Set` and false otherwise.

This is more efficient than solutions using only `ArrayList` as `contains` for a `HashSet` is `O(1)` whereas `contains` for an `ArrayList` is `O(n)`. However, this is only likely to make any noticeable difference for long lists.